# If a sequence is not bounded above, there exists an increasing subsquence, $b_n$ such that $1/b_n$ convergest to zero

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n$ > 0 and $(a_n)$ from n=1 to ∞ is not bounded above, then there exists an increasing subsequence $(b_n)$ such that $1/b_n$ converges to zero.

My attempt:

Let $(a_n)$ be an increasing sequence not bounded above. Since $(a_n)$ has no upper bound then $sup(a_n)$ =+∞. Since the sequence starts at 1, we know that a lower bound exists.

By the Balzano Weierstrass theorem, since a lower bound exists, we know that there exists a sub-sequence that converges. If we let $(b_n)$ be such sequence, Our goal is to prove that $1/b_n$ converges to zero.

I don't know where to go from there

Comment: "Since the sequence starts at $1$, we know that a lower bound exists": This doesn't make sense. (But since $a_n > 0$, we know that a lower bound exists $-$ for instance, $0$).

Comment: "since a lower bound exists, we know that there exists a sub-sequence that converges": no. For instance, $a_n = n$ has a lower bound, but no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Why should $1/b_n$ converge to zero, just because $b_n$ converges?

Comment: @LionelRicci: The answer to your question is "not much". We certainly can't deduce that $1/b_n$ tends to zero from the fact that $b_n$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: @TonyK I deleted my comment, realized it made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this attempt is not right. There is no reason to assume that $a_n$ is increasing. Your application of Bolzano-Weierstrass is incorrect, since that theorem requires $\{a_n\}$ to be bounded, not just bounded below. Finally, if $b_n$ is convergent (to a real number), then $1/b_n$ *cannot* converge to zero. It converges to $1/b$, where $b = \lim_n b_n$. That's not zero.

---

What you need is a sequence that runs off to infinity monotonically. One way to construct this is to take the $b_1$ as the first term of $\{a_n\}$ that exceeds $1$. Then let $b_2$ be the next term in the original sequence that exceeds both $2$ and $b_1$. Then let $b_3$ be the next term in the original sequence that exceeds both $3$ and $b_2$.....

Convince yourself that this process is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For all n, set $c_n=\min A_n$ where $A_n=\{k\in \mathbb N\vert a_k>n\}$ is a non-empty set (since $a_n$ is not bounded). Then set $b_n=a_{c_n}$

$\forall n\in \mathbb N,b_n>n$, hence $\frac 1 {b_n}<\frac 1 n$ converges to zero.

Now with this method we are not sure that $b_n$ is strictly increasing. There's a little tweak to get rid of that, instead of $\min A_n$ take $\min (A_n\backslash\{b_k\vert k<n\})$

And by the way, the problem with your method is that you assume that since $a_n$ is not bounded above and starts at 1, it is bounded below which is not always the case, consider $a_n=\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} n$

Comment: Not quite right: you want $c_n = \min A_n$, and $b_n = a_{c_n}$. (Also, $a_n$ _is_ bounded below, because we are given $a_n > 0.$)

Comment: Yeah thanks I edited it :)